# scrollIntoView not working with scrollLeft on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, scroll, addeventlistener

I'm using `scrollIntoView` to scroll to a particular section of my website. 
However on one of the sections, I used a `scroll` event listener to scroll the content horizontally as the page scrolls vertically by setting the element's `scrollLeft` to create a parallax effect.

**The scroll listener**

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => {
  // ...
  const elem = document.getElementById('experienceContainer');
  elem.scrollLeft = leftValue;
});
```

**Button to scroll to section**

```
<button onClick={() => {
  const doc = document.getElementById('bottom');
  doc.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
}}>
  Scroll to bottom
</button>
```

This works fine on mobile and desktop browsers. Its able to scroll to bottom, and the parallax effect is working. But for some reason, **it doesn't work on Desktop Chrome**.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: Is that really your HTML? Why have any JavaScript in your HTML anyways? Do it all externally.

Comment: @StackSlave I've forgotten to mention thats jsx. I'm using react JS. Thanks

Comment: have you tried triggering the scroll event manually?

Comment: There is indeed a bug, [here is an MCVE](https://jsfiddle.net/6893muoa/). [By specs](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#scrolling) only the boxes that are smooth scrolled should be canceled by an other call to *perform a scroll*, Chrome does this for any box. Now, running a quick bisect, I found this behavior as soon as v62 (maybe even before) so I doubt they'll consider it high priority even if we open an issue. But more importantly for this question, I guess you want a workaround rather than just a "yes there is a bug" answer. For this, we need more info on what you are doing exactly.